# PHP MVC - Can't delete cookie

Tags: php, cookies, model-view-controller

Hello i'm building my own simple MVC framework. When I tried to create login page all worked - session all ok. But when I try to work with cookies, it doesn't work. Exactly deleting cookie don't work. :( Please help me, i can't find any solutions on google. File code where I'm trying to delete cookie:

```
<?php
class HomeController extends Controller {

    function __construct(){
        $this->view = 'testView';
    }


    public function index($params){
        if(isset($_COOKIE['logged'])){
            echo "cookie exists";
        } else{
            if($_POST){
                if(isset($_POST['rr'])){
                    setcookie('logged', true, time()+3600);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public function logout($params){
        setcookie('logged', null, time()-3600);
    }

}
```

[My whole code](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/81k73c2kr85te/MVC_-_help)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to be sure about remove cookie you may do this way:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['logged'])) {
  setcookie('logged', null, -1, '/');        
  unset($_COOKIE['logged']);    
}
```